# When, in the Wolverine Cinematic timeline, does Logan get caught in Nagasaki?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, x-men-origins-wolverine, the-wolverine

Is it after the 'X-Men Origins' story (which seems impossible because when he was in the pit he had bone claws)  whereas a couple of minutes into Origins he is shown getting adamantium claws.

Can someone provide an in-universe chronology?

Comment: “Can someone provide an in-universe chronology?” — After *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, even Doctor Who would be at pains to explain it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite "Wibbly-Wobbly,timey-wimey" seems to make sense in any universe though.

Answer (score 3):

*X-Men Origins: Wolverine* takes place over the course of over 100 years.

In the movies, James Howlett (Wolverine) and his brother Victor (not brothers in the comic) are shown as having been born prior to the American Civil War (1861-1865), as they both participate in it. They fight in other wars over time. While they are shown in the montage together, this does not necessarily mean that they are together 100% of the time.

The Nagasaki scene during *The Wolverine* is an example of one of those times that they are not together. Nagasaki was bombed at the end of World War 2, on August 9, 1945.

The bulk story of *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* takes place in the late 70's. Specifically, the end of the movie supposedly takes place in 1979, as the final battle is supposedly the true cause of the [Three Mile Island Incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Mile_Island_accident). This means that Wolverine gets his claws in the X-Men Movie universe sometime in the late 70's.

---

So, to sum up:

- *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*: First few minutes of the movie (discovery of powers, tracking the brothers through time)
- *The Wolverine*: First few minutes of the movie, and repeated flashbacks (Surviving the bomb in Nagasaki and protecting/rescuing Yashida)
- *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*: Main story - working with Stryker and Team X, living in Canada with Kayla, getting his Adamantium claws. Loss of memories due to Adamantium Bullet.
- *The Wolverine*: Main story - living in Canada alone, being approached by Yukio, going to Tokyo to meet Yashida again.

Answer (score 3):

Mirroring events in our own universe, Logan is trapped in Nagasaki (in 'Wolverine') in 1945 whereas the events of 'X-Men : Origins' are supposed to have taken place in the late 1970s, leading up to the 1979 "Three Mile Island" incident.

This obviously explains why he doesn't have adamantium claws in the earlier part of the Wolverine film.

There's a quite excellent timeline here that may help you. Warning, epic spoilers: http://actionmoviefanatix.com/2014/04/07/whats-so-wrong-with-the-x-men-movies-anyway-the-timeline/

Comment: So does the nagasaki incident take place before meeting stryker whrn he was with creed or does it occor after he leaves stryker and meets kayla ?

Comment: Stryker was about ten years old when the Nagasaki bombing occurred.

Comment: If as u say nagasaki bombing occurred before meeting stryker then where was creed? He never leaves logan alone ... he is his brother and would have his back so I doubt that .....

Comment: Wolverine is imprisoned at that point in the movie. It's likely that Creed was imprisoned elsewhere

Comment: First off, they're in the military, so they are where their commanders put them. Second, in the wake of the Sullivan Brothers incident during World War 2, brothers in the US military were specifically *not allowed* to serve together in the same squad.

Comment: @Nihar During X-Men:Days of Future Past Logan is shown living alone, working as an enforcer/muscle for the mafia in New York city during the 1970's, so it stands to reason that he and Victor drifted in and out of each other's lives from time to time.